# Do function literals exist in TS?

Tags: typescript

I have a function `fn` defined and a method that should only be allowed to receive not just a function with an identical signature to `fn`, but the literal function implementation itself.

```
const fn = (x: number) => x+1

class Context {
    constructor(
        protected callback: fn
    ) { }
}
```

This errors

```
'fn' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof fn'?ts(2749)
type fn = /*unresolved*/ any
```

If I instead did

```
    constructor(
        protected callback: typeof fn
    ) { }
```

I believe that would only ensure identical signatures, allowing functions with different implementations.

Do function literals not exist in TS, like how number literals and string literals do?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. It sounds like you want a kind of nominal typing of callables, but TypeScript is _structurally_ typed - and why wouldn't any other function `(a: number) => number` be acceptable?

Comment: "*I have a function fn defined and a method that should only be allowed to receive not just a function with an identical signature to fn, but the literal function implementation itself.*" why? If *the only possible value for a parameter* is a constant, then why is it even a parameter? In what way is it useful to pass the function as opposed to just use it without requiring the caller to supply it? If we use another example, is `type AddFn = (x: 2, y: 2) => 4` really *useful* to have parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's not just one implementation of a function but a handful that you want to accept. If there's just one, then as the comments indicate, it's pointless to even *have* an argument.

But if we have several values we want to be able to supply, and we want to require the user to pick from *only* those values, that's called an `enum`.

```
enum CallbackType {
    AddOne,
    MultiplyByTwo,
    ReturnZero,
}

class Context {
    constructor(callbackType: CallbackType) {
        ...
    }
}

function performCallback(callbackType: CallbackType, arg: number) {
    switch (callbackType) {
    case CallbackType.AddOne:
        return arg + 1;
    case CallbackType.MultiplyByTwo:
        return arg * 2;
    case CallbackType.ReturnZero:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, rather than calling your "callback" argument directly, when you want to invoke the callback, do `performCallback(this.callbackType, whateverArgument);`